# "(?=.*[\s!@\$%\^\(\)-_=])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{14,20}" javascript regex allowing # and & which is not part of regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write javascript regex for password field to only allow some special char and space with alphanumeric, I don't want "#" to allow but below regex is allowing the # as well.

```
"(?=.*[\s!@\$%\^\(\)-_=])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{14,20}"
```

Comment: In your regex you have `.*` which allow every characters

Comment: I have tried changing the regex but not able to make could you help in writing this for me. my requirement is to create password validation allowing alphanumeric and "! @ $ % ^ ( ) - _ = " only these spceial character and space ,, will it possible

Comment: The above suggestion didn't work but issue is solved now